# Finding out whether Leaflet is using Canvas or SVG?

Tags: leaflet, svg, rendering

Leaflet maps use either an SVG or Canvas renderer.

How do I figure out which one a created leaflat map is using?

Comment: Examine http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-renderer

Comment: I did, but my_map.options.renderer is undefined! So it looks like the default is set somewhere else internally, and that option only matters if it's set manually. So the answer's got to be elsewhere!

Comment: Code which creates the renderer for a layer is here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.3.1/src/layer/vector/Renderer.getRenderer.js#L10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that, for most Leaflet objects, the `options` object given by the user gets merged with the class's defaults, overriding them. Then the class decides what to do with the result on initialisation, using some logic like `this._myopt = this.options.myopt`. So if you haven't provided a `Renderer` option, there isn't going to be one at `my_map.options.renderer` (there isn't for me either, and I didn't override the default).

However, `my_map._renderer` seems to be populated. You can check it against the renderer types using the `instanceof` operator:

```
mymap._renderer instanceof L.SVG
// true

mymap._renderer instanceof L.Canvas
// false
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also inspect your map panes (e.g. `<div class="leaflet-pane">`) and see if their children include `<svg>` or `<canvas>`